# getURL, parsing web-site with german special characters

Tags: r, geturl

I am using getURL() and htmlParse() - how can I make web-site content with special characters to be displayed properly?

```
        library(RCurl); library(XML)
        script <- getURL("http://www.floraweb.de/pflanzenarten/foto.xsql?suchnr=814")
        doc <- htmlParse(script, encoding = "UTF-8")
        xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id='content']//p", xmlValue)[2]
        [1] "Bellis perennis L., GÃ¤nseblÃ¼mchen"
        # should say:
        [1] "Bellis perennis L., Gänseblümchen"

        > sessionInfo()
    R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
    Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
    [5] LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252    

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] jpeg_0.1-2     RCurl_1.9-5.1  bitops_1.0-4.1 XML_3.9-1.1   

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] tools_2.14.1

options("encoding")
$encoding
[1] "native.enc"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on my system. Give some information about your system and locale. You should also include the necessary packages in your example.

Comment: sry. I edited the posting.. OS is Windows Vista.

Comment: works fine for me too, on 64 bit R on osx.

Comment: What is the result of this `getOption("encoding")`?

Comment: Also, FYI, R is now a full version ahead so you should upgrade to `2.15.0`

Comment: When looking at script I noticed, that charset=iso-8859-1. Maybe you need to use the encoding parameter of getURL.

Comment: try this: `script <- getURL("http://www.floraweb.de/pflanzenarten/foto.xsql?suchnr=814", .encoding = 'iso-8859-1')`

Comment: Sry, this doesn't work for me.. For the moment I helped myself with replacing the characters with gsub()..